# java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 when using MPAndroid chart library

Tags: java, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I am new to android studio.I try to use the MPAndroid chart in my app.So i followed the steps given in http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-charts-to-your-android-app-using-mpandroidchart--cms-23335.

But while building the app i am getting these errors :

1.

> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

2.

> Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

3.

> Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

I searched in google for the above errors but couldnt found the solution.
Please if anyone able to solve the above issue ,please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Are you using the .jar file? If so, there were issues with it, i just updated the jar file it's named the same but try downloading the new one and see if it works then. (hint: the invalid .jar is around 1,5MB, the good one around 750kb)

Answer (score 0):

By the "c:\" paths, I see you are using Windows. If your Windows is 64 bits, be sure that every process calls other processes from the same number of bits. I mean: 64 bits processes may call only other 64 bits processes, and the same goes for 32 bits processes.

In your case, check that both the Android Studio and the JDK are made for the same number of bits.